# Python regex findall returning empty list after parsing a text file

Tags: python, regex, python-re, findall

I'm trying to parse some conversations from an app in a .txt file with Python's re module, but despite working on [regex101](https://regex101.com) when used on a sample of the file, it doesn't work properly when I open the file and actually try to parse it.

The structure of the txt file is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm - Message Author: message text\n`, and I'm trying to get only the `Name: message \n` parts. I'm using the following pattern `(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\-\s)(.*:.*$)`. My code is looking more or less like the following:

```py
buffer = open(file, 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8').read()
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\-\s)(.*:\s)(.*$)')
matches = re.findall(pattern, buffer)
```

As the title says, though, findall returns and empty list, and I don't know why. The following sample works as expected on regex101:

```
20/04/2021 09:54 - Person 1: this is an example text. Will it match?
20/04/2021 09:54 - Person 2: I think it does.
```

Comment: This code works as expected for me.  Your input file must be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, John. I'll take a look at it to see if something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Lookarounds are "expensive". Better match what you want and ***capture*** the interesting parts.
That said, you might get along with a simpler expression:

```
^\d+[^-]+-\s+(?P<person>[^:]+):\s+(?P<text>.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CuK9bw/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Kiss: **remove `$`**. It matches the end of string. You need to match end of lines, and `re.M` could be helpful here. But removing `$` is simply simpler.

```py
(?<=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\-\s)(.*:\s)(.*)
```

BUT even "kiss"er: you do not need lookbehind or escapes over slashes because `re.findall` returns *captured strings* if you use a capturing group in the expression.

Use

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s*\d{2}:\d{2}\s*-\s*(?P<name>.*):\s*(?P<message>.*)')
with open(file, 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8') as buffer:
    matches = [match.groupdict() for match in pattern.finditer(test_str)]
```

[Regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/2tzk0n/1) | [**Python code**](https://tio.run/##dVBNT8MwDL33V1i7LJ20tAvdgQjYmdtuHChCofXWiOZDjpGG0H57ycrghmQ/@VnWe0@OnzwEfzNN1sVADIQFY@LXxAT3sFB1VTeVqtUG6lu9bWANe6QUPGw08GAT5DIe8GRcHBEYTyzhyY4jWAZnuBt2rf9fRWl4vOj498t9HzDJRRENM5LP/oSyCy7aEQUt27e2/1Ln6g@bc5tWM9MzZrbOLXb7O28cPshVqa/cYUrmOK@WZRHJehbwPOeTRwofsbcdixIOgX5Sg/VwzSEP1vc2T@L3M@ULlNP0DQ)

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```